# how to set onclicklistener to items in current page?

Tags: android, paging

I have an application where i want to add onclicklistener to my individual items in pager.
Below is my screen shot . please some one tell me how to add onclicklistener to individual image in this current page .
[image]

Thanks
below is my code for pager view.
 here when 1st time run the app initialize the every view page, when i try to click on image it return only last image info. But i want the current image info.

```
    scroller = ((Pager)findViewById(R.id.scrollView));
    indicator = ((PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator));
    indicator.setPager(scroller);
   // Pager pager = new Pager(this, attrs)

    //indicator.getActivePage();

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View pageView = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
         pageView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
       // ((TextView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.pageText)).setText("Page " + (i+1));
          c=4*i;
         imageView1 = (ImageView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         imageView1.setImageResource(icons[c]);
         imageView2 = (ImageView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
         imageView2.setImageResource(icons[c+1]);
         imageView3 = (ImageView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
         imageView3.setImageResource(icons[c+2]);
         imageView4 = (ImageView) pageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
         imageView4.setImageResource(icons[c+3]);

       // pageView.setBackgroundColor(COLORS[i % COLORS.length]);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("helo i clicked==>"+c);

            }
        });
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("helo i clicked==>"+c);
            }
        });
       imageView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("helo i clicked==>"+c);
            }
        });
       imageView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("helo i clicked==>"+c);
        }
    });
        scroller.addPage(pageView);
    }
```

Comment: Accept anyone's answer which one you've satisfied..!

Answer (score 2):

It seem to be you didn't read information available at android developers.

Use below  code to add onClickListener for images. I don't know whether you are using ImageView or ImageButton. I took ImageView.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(/**Context you have to pass**/);

iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // do whatever you want
        }
    });
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

set this on your images..or button

in the xml such that

`<Button [...]
   android:onClick: "onClick" [...]
 />`

"onClick": name this whatever you want your method name that handles clicks to be

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by assigning onClickListeners to Image Buttons. You can use Image buttons to display these images and set onClickListeners on them. Perhaps something like this can help?

```
   ImageButton   button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ImageView` then set the property `OnClick` to **true**.